# How to link two radio buttons (RadioType) with Symfony 5?

Tags: symfony

How can I link two RadioType (with same name) like this:

```
<div class="radioTel">
    <input class="radio" type="radio" id="madame" name="sex" value="Madame">
    <label for="madame">Mme</label>
</div>
<div class="radioTel">
    <input class="radio" type="radio" id="monsieur" name="sex" value="Monsieur">
    <label for="monsieur">Mr</label>
</div>
```

I'm tring with this in $builder:

```
        ->add('sex', RadioType::class, [
            'label' => 'Mme',
            'data' => 'Madame'
        ])
        ->add('sex', RadioType::class, [
            'label' => 'Mr',
            'data' => 'Monsieur'
        ])
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Use the `ChoiceType` with `expanded` set to `true`, then render manually if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [ChoiceType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) instead of a RadioType